# Options are not passed to the class

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass options to the class via the constructor from the appsettings.json file.
The file itself looks like this:

```
    "IDP": {
    "UrlCbr": "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js",
    "UrlDadata": "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/currency",
    "DadataToken": "94dabe1e8342c21fdad9622be29514d4f0f99bbd8",
    "BotToken": "1549046386:AAHJsdsaMVaCT-8O3D_P8VLxw6EKAr4P9JfSU",
    "BotName": "Hop_hipBot",
    "BotUrl": "https://111295d46c69.ngrok.io/{0}"
  }
```

To do this, I created the IDP.cs class:

```
public class IDP
    {
        public string UrlCbr { get; set; }
        public string UrlDadata { get; set; }
        public  string DadataToken { get; set; }
        public  string BotToken { get; set; }
        public  string BotName { get; set; }
        public  string BotUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the Startup.cs I'm making a connection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.Configure<IDP>(Configuration.GetSection("IDP"));
        }
```

I need this data in the implementation of the bot:

```
class Bot 
    {
        private static TelegramBotClient botClient;
        private static IOptions<IDP> _IDPs;

        public void Temp(IOptions<IDP> IDPs)
        {
            _IDPs = IDPs;
        }

        public static async Task<TelegramBotClient> GetBotClientAsync()
        {
            if (botClient != null)
            {
                return botClient;
            }
            botClient = new TelegramBotClient(_IDPs.Value.BotToken);
            var hook = string.Format(_IDPs.Value.BotUrl, @"api/bot");
            await botClient.SetWebhookAsync(hook);
            return botClient;
        }
    }
```

Well, the bot itself is launched in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            Bot.GetBotClientAsync().Wait();

        }
```

And when you run the entire application, the `_IDPs` field in the bot turns out to be `null`. Why is this happening and how do I need to properly deliver the data to the bot? In other classes, everything works correctly and options are passed

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the Bot class. Change:

```
 public void Temp(IOptions<IDP> IDPs)
        {
            _IDPs = IDPs;
        }
```

To :

```
public class Bot 
{
 .....

private static IOptions<IDP> _IDPs;
public Bot(IOptions<IDP> IDPs)
        {
            _IDPs = IDPs;
        }
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below:

```
public class Bot
{
    private static IOptions<IDP> _IDPs;

    public static void Temp(IOptions<IDP> IDPs)
    {
        _IDPs = IDPs;
    }

    public static async Task GetBotClientAsync()
    {
        var data = _IDPs.Value.BotToken;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //more services...
    services.Configure<IDP>(Configuration.GetSection("IDP"));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    Bot.Temp(serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<IDP>>());
    Bot.GetBotClientAsync().Wait();

}
```

Result:
[image]